# Can I use a C++ template library from a C program?

Tags: c++, c, templates

My knowledge of C++ is limited. I understand that C++ libraries can be called from C provided a C interface is available. Is it possible to call a C++ template library defined in a `.hpp` file from a C library? For example, this wonderful [expression evaluation](https://fastmathparser.codeplex.com/) library.

It may be time to learn C++!
OK. Here is a first try:

```
#ifndef EXPRTK_C_H_
#define EXPRTK_C_H_
#include "exprtk.hpp"

//Header
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef exprtk::symbol_table<double>      symbol_table_t;
typedef exprtk::expression<double>          expression_t;
typedef exprtk::parser<double>                  parser_t;

  void add_variable_(symbol_table_t st, char* name, double *value);
  void register_symbol_table_(expression_t ex, symbol_table_t st);
  void compile_(parser_t parser, char *expression_string, expression_t ex);
  double evaluate_(expression_t ex);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* EXPRTK_C_H_ */


#include "exprtk.hpp"
#include "exprtk_c.hpp"
```

Here is the .cpp file. `trig_function()` is the real example, used in `main()`. What follows is my attempt at wrapping the functions. Error message is with parser.

```
exprtk.hpp:16962:7: error: ‘exprtk::parser<T>::parser(const exprtk::parser<T>&) [with T = double]’ is private
exprtk_simple_example_01.cpp:85:83: error: within this context
exprtk_simple_example_01.cpp:60:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void compile_(parser_t, char*, expression_t)’

template<typename T>
void trig_function() {
    std::string expression_string =
            "clamp(-1.0,sin(2 * pi * x) + cos(x / 2 * pi),+1.0)";
    T x;
    exprtk::symbol_table<T> symbol_table;
    symbol_table.add_variable("x", x);
    symbol_table.add_constants();

    exprtk::expression<T> expression;
    expression.register_symbol_table(symbol_table);

    exprtk::parser<T> parser;
    parser.compile(expression_string, expression);

    for (x = T(-5.0); x <= T(+5.0); x += 0.001) {
        T y = expression.value();
        printf("%19.15f\t%19.15f\n", x, y);
    }
}



//Cpp file
void add_variable_(symbol_table_t st, char *varname, double *value) {
    const std::string varname_ = varname;
    bool r = st.add_variable(varname_, *value);
    printf("%d\n", r);
    r = st.add_constants();
}

void register_symbol_table_(expression_t ex, symbol_table_t st) {
    ex.register_symbol_table(st);
}
void compile_(parser_t parser,char *expression_string, expression_t ex) {
    const std::string expression_string_ = expression_string;
    parser.compile(expression_string_, ex);
}

double evaluate_(expression_t ex) {
    double val = ex.value();
    return (val);
}

int main() {
    trig_function<double>();

    double x;
    //exprtk::symbol_table<double> symbol_table;
    symbol_table_t symbol_table;
    add_variable_(symbol_table, "x", &x);
    symbol_table.add_constants();

    //exprtk::expression<double> expression;
    expression_t expression;
    register_symbol_table_(expression, symbol_table);

    //exprtk::parser<double> parser;
    parser_t parser;
    compile_(parser, "clamp(-1.0,sin(2 * pi * x) + cos(x / 2 * pi),+1.0)", expression);

    double q = -5.0, y = 0.0;
    for (x = q; x <= +5.0; x += 0.001) {
        y = evaluate_(expression);
        printf("%19.15f\t%19.15f\n", x, y);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry! You can't.  There is no templates in C.

Comment: A C++ wrapper for an instantiated template makes sense. I will give this a try and report back. I apologize if this comment should have been with the answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Definitely learn C++.

You could hide the templates in a cpp file and expose an interface to use them:

```
//Header
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  void push(int elt);
  int pop();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

//Cpp file
static std::deque<int> queue;

void push(int elt) {
  queue.push_back(elt);
}

int pop() {
  auto tmp = queue.front();
  queue.pop_front();
  return tmp;
}
```

You can't instantiate a template via C, but you can use a header file that takes advantage of templates behind the scenes and link everything together. That said, I strongly recommend leaving C in the past, and learning C++; it grants more power, speed, and safety.

Comment: You need `#if __cplusplus` to protect the `extern "C"` designation, which is not part of the C grammar.

Comment: @jbgs - The C++ language gives you the ability to more clearly express your *high level intent* to the compiler. This in turn lets it optimize better. This of course says nothing of what can be said if we require that we speak of 'idiomatic' and 'maintainable' C and C++, in which case C++ wins hands down if we talk of templates alone. Consider `std::qsort` and `std::sort`, as a classic example of 'faster C++'.

Comment: I agree that it may be easier to write very efficient code in C++, but we cannot say C++ is faster than C in absolute terms. Some benchmarks: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/

Comment: I really can. C++ is a strict superset in terms of power and expressiveness. The Stepanov Abstraction Penalty is a thing of the past - the abstraction helps, it does not hurt anymore. I do not find your benchmark reference reliable. Pick a task, set an expert C programmer and an expert C++ programmer to it, I'll place my bet. That said, both of them could use inline assembly (and thus theoretically have *equal* power), but that's just silly, and would almost certainly be slower anyway. Ask them to write code that would pass an industry code review, the difference in performance will be clear.

Comment: @Mark. very helpful. must learn C++. Expressiveness, clarity & fantastic libraries is a winning combination.

Comment: @jbgs: C++ has stricter aliasing rules than C. That means that a write through pointer `p` is less likely to invalidate a prior read through `q`. This can save an expensive re-read of `*q`. Also, optimizers are much better in outlining C++ exception-handling code than C's error return values. (Outlining is an optimization for rarely-used code, the opposite of inlining)

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

C does not support templates, so no C interface can be available.